# Could somebody correct my reasoning for Buffon's needle problem?

Tags: probability

I'm getting $1/4$ as the probability in Buffon's needle problem and I'm having some trouble finding my mistake.

The problem statement:

> If a needle of length 1 is dropped at random on a surface ruled
> with parallel lines at distance 2 apart, what is the probability that the needle will cross one
> of the lines?

I reduced the problem to a simpler one:

> If a needle of length one is dropped in a region of length two such that its center lies on a horizontal line, creating an angle theta with that line, what is the probability that it will contact a vertical line at the center of said region?

[image: Visualization]

(Visualization)

From simple trig rules, the needle will begin contact when the center is $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{2}$ away from the central line, and likewise ends contact at the same distance.

So we have a total sample space of 2 and a hit-space of $\cos(\theta)$, so we get a probability to hit of $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{2}$. (Assume $0\le\theta\le2\pi$)

Graphing our space over all possible theta we have:

[image: Visualization]

Calculating the probability of placing a needle in the hit region of our sample space is simply the hit area (blue) divided by the total area.

So we get $$P=\frac{4(\frac{1}{2}\cdot1\cdot\frac{\pi}{2})}{4\pi}=\frac{1}{4}$$

We can extend these regions both horizontally and vertically without affecting the probability, so this 'solution' claims the answer to the problem is $1/4$.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: In the Buffon needle problem the final answer depends on how a "random" placement of the needle is defined. It may be one of the ways is yours by choosing needle center then angle, and another is something else like say choose 2 points and throw out all cases of length being too long or short. Anyway in a treatment I saw there were definitely two different answers depending on setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't the graph of cosine!!!

The area under the curve of abs(cosx) between zero and 2pi is 4. The total sample space area is 4pi. So the probability is 1/pi as desired.